# ImageCropper.maui setup

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, maui

I have a quick question. Im unable to initialize ImageCropper in MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate.cs files. According to documentation(https://libraries.io/nuget/ImageCropper.Maui/1.0.3), the syntax is following:

```
new ImageCropper.Maui.Platform.Init();
```

But in the class Platform, there is no Init() function. Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the [sample](https://github.com/jbowmanp1107/ImageCropper.Maui/blob/main/ImageCropperDemo/Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs) code, the correct syntax is

```
new ImageCropper.Maui.Platform().Init(this);
```